# Split container Panel  issues in winforms C# Visual Studio

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I got Panel 1 and `Panel 2` using `splitContainer` in the Windows form. I want to keep the original size of the `Panel 1` . I just want to maximize the size of the `Panel 2` from the original starting point when I maximize the form in the interface.

I tried to change the setting in the `splitContainer` properties `dock` but i couldn't succeed....

How can I maximize the `Panel 2` alone ????

[image: The original one]

[image: I want the the panel2 will be like this]

When I checked this link, there is no solution for my problem. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953934

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the **SplitContainer.FixedPanel** property to whichever panel you want to keep fixed, or use simple panels and anchor them properly to your needs.

[image: Sample using panels]

Comment: I just want to maximize the `panel2` in the winform.

Comment: You are right. The FixedPanel property preserves the selected panel's Width value and alters the Height only. I don't think that it is possible to preserve one panel' size (width and height) while altering the other's. You could use simple (properly anchored) panels instead.

Comment: @ Daniel Vlasceanu:  I guess, i should go with simple panels as per your suggestion.

Comment: Could you elaborate little bit more?? Now i'm using `2 panels` and I just want to maximize `panel2` when i maximize the form??

Comment: Anchor Panel1 to Top and Left, and anchor the Panel2 to all margins (Top, Bottom, Left and Right). You can set these anchors in code or in the Properties window of each panel. This way, Panel1 will stay fixed and Panel2 will resize with **its container**. ( http://bit.ly/JRxLuL ).

Comment: I tried your instruction, still it remains same(the panel2 is not re-sizing when i maximize the form).

Comment: Please share your project, on skydrive for example. I'll try to tweak it for you, if you want to.

Comment: Daniel Vlasceanu: I don't have skydrive account i'll upload to rapidshare https://rapidshare.com/files/2483249922/Panel.zip

Comment: https://rapidshare.com/files/2437461962/Panel.zip please try any one of the links.